# Rspec Test Always Failed for Class Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

as the subject said. It is seems the implemented code always `create` a new record instead of get existing one.

Here is my rspec test code:

```
describe "#from_facebook" do 
  it "return existing related user" do 
    existing_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user_from_facebook = User.from_facebook({ uid: existing_user.uid })
    expect(user_from_facebook.email).to eql existing_user.email
  end
end
```

and here is the test implementation:

```
def self.from_facebook(fb_auth)
where(provider: "facebook", uid: fb_auth[:uid]).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = fb_auth[:email]
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
  end
end
```

I always got this:

```
1) User#from_facebook return existing related user
 Failure/Error: expect(user_from_facebook.email).to eql existing_user.email

   expected: "karolann.gulgowski@satterfield.us"
        got: nil

   (compared using eql?)
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:48:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And here are the console results via puts.
for `existing_user`:

```
#<User id: 105, email: "karolann.gulgowski@satterfield.us", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$90uzEdbwfnqfUL0CDhNOH.THUbzovFyJK1OPg7VcgxL...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2015-08-30 04:12:59", updated_at: "2015-08-30 04:12:59", auth_token: "vkvm2-fLe5x1dZGbewqw", provider: nil, uid: "133290925">
```

for `user_from_facebook`:

```
#<User id: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: "$2a$04$lxdBWBsXY4febfgurgHJKOdNcOMCuQQO2DHshWChnxA...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, auth_token: "", provider: "facebook", uid: "133290925">
```

Please let me know what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note: User.from_facebook({ uid: existing_user.uid }) can be written without the curly braces: User.from_facebook(uid: existing_user.uid )

Comment: What's wrong ? Check the outputs you have listed. Your facebook user object has no email i.e. Nil but your user object has an email. So nil == me@me.com is false. Hence the test fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` factory doesn't fully setup the user. It creates the following `user` object:

```
#<User id: 105,
       email: "karolann.gulgowski@satterfield.us",
       encrypted_password: "$2a$04$90uzEdbwfnq...",
       reset_password_token: nil,
       reset_password_sent_at: nil,
       remember_created_at: nil,
       sign_in_count: 0,
       current_sign_in_at: nil,
       last_sign_in_at: nil,
       current_sign_in_ip: nil,
       last_sign_in_ip: nil,
       created_at: "2015-08-30 04:12:59",
       updated_at: "2015-08-30 04:12:59",
       auth_token: "vkvm2-fLe5x1dZGbewqw",
       provider: nil,
       uid: "133290925"
```

Note that the provider is `nil`. Thus, your `from_facebook` method (which looks for the uuid **and** the provider) cannot find the user.

As a solution, use the following to create your `existing_user` in the spec:

```
existing_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, provider: 'facebook')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting a `uid` in the `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`?

Can you post the content of your `user` factory?  You might want to create a `facebook_user` factory that sets a unique `uid`

Comment: thanks @Josh, as mentioned by @tessi, it was because I'm not set the `:provider` property of the `user`.